# тест метода с http(тестирование Rspec-ом)

Tags: ruby, gems, rspec

Есть метод

require 'httparty'

```
def distance_calculation
    url = "https://api.distancematrix.ai/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=# 
    {@departure}&destinations=#{@destination}&key=lugtcyuuvliub;o;o"
    response = HTTParty.get(url)
    distance = response.parsed_response["rows"].first["elements"].first["distance"]. 
    ["text"]

end

К нему тест

describe "#cargo" do
  context "distance" do
    it "returns hash with destination addresses, origin addresses & rows of datas" do
  end
end

Как протестировать Rspec-ом метод в котором применяется гем httparty и как бы он ничего не возвращает, записывает в переменную распарсенное поле (расстояние в км).
Заранее благодарю всех, кто откликнется.
```

Comment: Обычно используют webmock для этих целей, он позволяет стабить запросы к внешним ресурсам.

Comment: Ваш метод (как и любой другой в руби) всегда возвращает результат выполнения последней строки, кстати

Answer (score 0):

Обычно используют [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) или [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).